# Algebric inequality

Tags: inequality

I am wondering for an algebric proofs (without calculus, lagrangian etc. because I didn't study yet) for: 
Let $x,y,z$ positive numbers such that $x+y+z=3$ and $n\in[0,4]$. Show that
$$
\frac{1}{n+(x+y)^3}+\frac{1}{n+(y+z)^3}+\frac{1}{n+(z+x)^3}\ge\frac{3}{n+8}.
$$
I obteined a proof for $n=0$. We have to prove $$\frac{1}{(x+y)^3}+\frac{1}{(y+z)^3}+\frac{1}{(z+x)^3}\ge\frac{3}{8}.
$$
Applying AM-GM twice, it follows
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\left(  x+y\right)  ^{3}}+\frac{1}{\left(  y+z\right)  ^{3}}+\frac
{1}{\left(  z+x\right)  ^{3}}  & =\frac{1}{\left(  3-z\right)  ^{3}}+\frac
{1}{\left(  3-x\right)  ^{3}}+\frac{1}{\left(  3-y\right)  ^{3}}\\
& \geq\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{\left[  \left(  3-x\right)  \left(  3-y\right)
\left(  3-z\right)  \right]  ^{3}}}\\
& =\frac{3}{\left(  3-x\right)  \left(  3-y\right)  \left(  3-z\right)  }\\
& \geq\frac{3}{8},%
\end{align*}%$$
because
$$
\sqrt[3]{\left(  3-x\right)  \left(  3-y\right)  \left(  3-z\right)  }%
\leq\frac{9-x-y-z}{3}=2\Rightarrow\frac{1}{8}\leq\frac{1}{\left(  3-x\right)
\left(  3-y\right)  \left(  3-z\right)  }.%
$$
For $n=4$ I did not obtein anything.

Comment: this inequality is true for all 0<= n<=36/5

Comment: @Booldy Yes you are right! We can prove it by Vasc's LCF Theorem.